# Understanding the parameters in google.search()

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

I am attempting to get the top 5 URL's for specific book abbreviations. I have the parameter num set to 5, which I assumed would return the top 5 results, and stop=1, which I interpreted to mean that after the 5 results were returned, no more HTTP requests would be sent. For some reason, when I set num=5 and stop=1, I only get 3 results, and I get the same 3 results for the proceeding titles searched (which obviously should be different). Additionally, I am hitting HTTP Error 503 when testing to solve this problem despite sleeping the loop, which others on this site suggested would prevent that error. My code is as follows...

```
    import random
    import time

    count = 0

    my_file = open('sometextfile.txt','r')

    for aline in my_file:
        print("******************************")
        print(aline)
        count += 1
        record_list = aline.split("\t")

        if "." in record_list[1]:
            search_results = google.search(record_list[2],num=5,stop=1,pause=3.)
            for result in search_results:
                print(result)
        time.sleep(random.randrange(0,3))
```

and has the following output...

```
    4   Environmental and Behaviour ['0143-005X']

******************************
4   Sustainable Cities and Society  ['0143-005X']

******************************
4   Chicago to LA: Making sense of urban theory ['0272-4944']

******************************
4   As adopted by the International Health Conference   ['0272-4944']

******************************
5   J. Wetl.    ['1442-9985']

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nlmcatalog?term=1442-9985%5BISSN%5D
http://www.wiley.com/bw/journal.asp?ref=1442-9985
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-AEC.html
******************************
5   Curr. Opin. Environ. Sustain.   ['1442-9985']

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nlmcatalog?term=1442-9985%5BISSN%5D
http://www.wiley.com/bw/journal.asp?ref=1442-9985
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-AEC.html
******************************
5   For. Policy Econ.   ['1442-9985']

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nlmcatalog?term=1442-9985%5BISSN%5D
http://www.wiley.com/bw/journal.asp?ref=1442-9985
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-AEC.html
******************************
5   For. Policy Econ.   ['1442-9985']

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nlmcatalog?term=1442-9985%5BISSN%5D
http://www.wiley.com/bw/journal.asp?ref=1442-9985
http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-AEC.html
******************************
5   Asia. World Dev.    ['1442-9985']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/Programming/Ibata Arens Project/google_search.py", line 27, in <module>
    for result in search_results:
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\__init__.py", line 304, in search
    html = get_page(url)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\__init__.py", line 121, in get_page
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 696, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I am also wondering if it would be better to simply use urllib and scrape through the html returned instead as my goal is simply to retrieve the ISSNs for each abbreviated book title.

Comment: Automated requests is against the google TOS, hence the 503. Google has an API you can use for free, up to 100 queries per day.

Comment: Right, but isn't this the Google API or am I missing something?